# iOS: Switching from JSON to CoreData for keeping local persistent data; is this practical? Dictionary within array within dictionary within array

Tags: ios, json, core-data, swift

I started last month with Swift and iOS. I'm working on an iPhone fitness app, specifically for weightlifting. Until now I've just been using a JSON file in the app's documents folder to store all the user's workouts, and using `let workoutData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData( . . . ) as NSArray` to load the data from the file (for display in a UITableView-like format) and then adding new workout entries with:

```
let newEntry: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newData, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
newEntry.writeToFile(documentsPath, atomically: true)
```

This worked fine at first, but now I need to be able to edit workouts, add new ones at arbitrary dates, or delete specific workouts. This requires a fair amount of looping through arrays within dictionaries within arrays, and sorting the workouts properly has become difficult.

I feel like CoreData may be the best option going forward, considering the nature of my data. That said, here's an example of the structure of my JSON database:

```
    [
  {
  "day": "Thursday",
  "date": "June 5 2014",
  "lbs": true,
  "lifts": [
            {
            "name": "SQUAT",
            "sets": 1,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 205,
            "warmup": true
            },
            {
            "name": "SQUAT",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 245,
            },
            {
            "name": "BENCH PRESS",
            "sets": 1,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 135,
            "warmup": true
            },
            {
            "name": "BENCH PRESS",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 185
            },
            {
            "name": "YATES ROW",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 135,
            }
            ]
  },
  {
  "day": "Wednesday",
  "date": "June 3 2014",
  "lbs": true,
  "lifts": [
            {
            "name": "DEADLIFT",
            "sets": 1,
            "reps": 3,
            "weight": 255,
            "warmup": true
            },
            {
            "name": "DEADLIFT",
            "sets": 1,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 305,
            },
            {
            "name": "OVERHEAD PRESS",
            "sets": 1,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 95,
            "warmup": true
            },
            {
            "name": "OVERHEAD PRESS",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 125
            },
            {
            "name": "CHIN-UPS",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 5,
            "weight": 180,
            }
            ]
  },
  {
  "day": "Monday",
  "date": "June 1 2014",
  "lbs": true,
  "lifts": [

  ]
  }
  ]
```

So the structure is:

1. Top level array, containing each workout day dictionary
2. Workout day dictionary, with a day string, date string, and an array of lifts
3. Array of lifts, each lift itself a dictionary
4. Lift dictionary, containing the lift name, sets, reps, weight, and a bool indicating whether this was a warmup set.

CoreData entities seem to only allow rather simple attributes. I suppose I could use a "Transformable" attribute, or use lots of To-Many relationships, but I'd rather not go to the trouble of learning those if it's not necessary.

So, should I suck it up and figure out how to make this same structure happen in CoreData? Alternatively, is this data structure too complex? Should I get rid of arrays/dictionaries altogether and just have a flat "workout" entity, and then *after* loading data from CoreData, collect all the workouts of the same date/type into groups manually in a ViewController?

Or, given the nature of my data, is there something better suited to use rather than CoreData or JSON? SQLite, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd use CoreData or CloudKit (for online storage). The reason why is if I'm a user and I've got workouts spanning a year and a ton of data within each workout. That's going to take forever to load into memory. So you're going to have to figure out a way to segment your data anyways or else your users could be waiting a while for the file to be read into memory or possibly, the file could get bigger than is allotted and it wouldn't be possible to read in.

I don't know why you're saying it would be difficult to store these into database. It looks like to me you already have a structure that could be translated to a DBMs fairly easily. You're tables I would think should look something like this:

- Workout : Table #1

  - wid (primary key)
  - date (timestamp)
  - lifts (array of: foreign keys)
- Lifts : Table #2

  - lid (primary key)
  - name (string)
  - sets (number)
  - reps (number)
  - weight (number)
  - warmup (bool)

Don't be scared of Databases, they're really not that bad and it'll be 1000% more efficient than storing them in files.

Comment: So would it be best to define structure in the database, rather than myself? I could always simply have a big database of lifts, and add a date property; then when I'm populating the TableView, I could select a range of dates, and then populate each date section with all the lifts on that date. Is this bad?

Comment: Sorry, first time on StackOverflow. I hit return thinking that it would start a new line.

Comment: @Hal Nope, that's the way to do it. Basically, you'll use `NSPredicates` to "select" your rows in the databases Table, you'll get your data back and you'll use that to populate your UITableViews.